# Resource location must not be null

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am using intellij and here are my settings when running a java program:

Working directory: `c:/Users/myuser/configuration/properties`

VM optiions: `-Dserver.ssl.trust-store=config/keystore.jks - Dserver.ssl.trust-store-password=changeit`

My directory structure is:

.. /configuration/properties/config/keystore.jks

But I keep on getting Resource must not be null error. How shoukd I set the vm options properly? I tried using full path and "file:/" but same error